# How to run multiple commands via python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have problem with my code, I want to run a commands on my virual machines via sockets. I found problem with multiple tasks,commands. For example if I open Excel my socket server has been freezed and I cannot run another command via cmd before I close excel application manually.

What I should change in code to open multiple applications in one time on my virtual machine? (for example. I want to open in one time four xlsx files)

Server.py

```py
import socket
import subprocess
import os
from threading import Thread


def check_ping(hostname):
    response = os.system("ping " + hostname)
    # and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
        pingstatus = "Network Active"
    else:
        pingstatus = "Network Error"

    return(pingstatus)

def run_path(path):
    response = os.system(path)
    # and then check the response..
    return('ok')



def Main():
    host = "localhost"
    port = 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))

    mySocket.listen(1)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if not data:
                    break
            #print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))

            #data = str(data)
            #hostname = data.replace('ping ', '')

            print ("sending: " + str(data))
            #print(hostname)
            conn.send(data.encode())
            if 'ping' in str(data):
                hostname = data.replace('ping ', '')
                pingstatus = check_ping(hostname)
                print(pingstatus)
            elif 'open' in str(data):
                path = str(data).replace('open ', '')

                run_path(path)





    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Client.py

```py
import socket

def Main():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000

        mySocket = socket.socket()
        mySocket.connect((host,port))

        message = input(" -> ")

        while message != 'q':
                mySocket.send(message.encode())
                data = mySocket.recv(1024).decode()

                print ('Received from server: ' + data)

                message = input(" -> ")

        mySocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Te be able to run a new command before the previous one has returned, you have just not to wait for that event. That means that you should use the subprocess module instead of the `system` function:

```
def run_path(path):
    response = subprocess.Process(path, shell=True)
    # and then continue without waiting...
    return('ok')
```

But it does not really make sense if you want to return anything to the peer. In addition, it does not really make sense to launch a GUI program from a remote client without being able to control it, nor even to stop it.

I am afraid you a chasing a weird animal here...

Comment: :(, 

I need python 'agent' on virtual machines and that agent will activate different scripts, applications via cmd. For example. 


I want on machine X run three python scripts in same time. After that I want simple report which scripts finished success and which one failed.

Comment: @Kagemar: no problem (except security...) for starting many non interactive scripts that way. Simply the remote will not know what was the result of the scripts.